# How do I add a root certificate to the WP7 Emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ssl-certificate

I have a certificate, `cert.crt`, which I have exported to `cert-der.cer` to try and add to my WP7 emulator. I have them both at addresses http://example.com/cert.crt and http://example.com/cert-der.cer and locally within my project. When I try to navigate a WebBrowser to the internet addresses nothing happens, and when I try to navigate to the local addresses I only see the name. I tried to access the certificates through Gmail's web interface, but still nothing. Is there any way to make the WP7 emulator see my certificate?

For the record, I don't have access to an IIS server, so I can't use WP7CertInstaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the http://example.com/cert.crt file with the Internet Explorer and not with an WebBrowser object. 
If you want to start the navigation process within your app use a WebBrowserTask or a HyperlinkButton

```
<HyperlinkButton TargetName="_blank" Content="SilverlightShow" NavigateUri="http://example.com/cert.crt" />
```